# Where to acquire / create LED optics

Tags: electrical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, lighting, traffic-light

I'm working on a few projects that require lenses to focus LED light flashes, similar to those lenses used by police lights (TIR lens) and other strobe traffic lighting utilizing Fresnel lenses. I've scoured the internet and cannot find anyone selling just the lenses or any guides on how they are/can be made in custom situations. I've provided a few examples below:

[Link 1](https://sc04.alicdn.com/kf/HTB19RlhkcbI8KJjy1zdq6ze1VXaM.jpg)

[Link 2](http://www.trafficlightwizard.com/images/products/detail/MVC006F.1.JPG)

I found an [article](https://streets.mn/2015/03/03/a-gallery-of-traffic-signal-lenses-and-leds/) detailing such traffic light lenses and that currently they are chiefly made out of polycarbonate but not anything further.

I am asking how to create these lenses and or trying to find a place that will allow me to purchase them.

Comment: It is fair to say you would like to know how to build these lenses used as described in your question.

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena Yes, it is fair to say that I am asking either how to build them and or a place to purchase them.

Comment: @jsotola I am trying to figure out how to build these lenses.

Comment: Those are custom molded items. You would need to be able to design them which will require rather expensive raytracing software and then contact a molder to design and build a mold. Very expense.

Comment: @EricS, if op was to create a lens from scratch or from know point, where would op start. I am also curious, Can one use a 3D printer to create a prototype?

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena No 3D printer I’m aware of prints optical grade materials or with optical grade finishes.

Comment: Making your own from scratch (=not duplicating an existing one) is a heavyweight task. Generating the geometric form which meets the photometric regulations needs real optics engineering knowledge. There really are strict regulations for traffic and warning lights. The needed, say 100nm or better  surface smoothness is another thing - especially, if the forms are more complex than a convex looking glass.   But check this, if you want to make a copy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TN9tHJXXlKs In the video a hobbyist makes an inferior copy of an existing  not so high quality very simple lens.

Answer (score 1):

[Alibaba](https://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&CatId=&SearchText=LED+lens) is the best place to begin sourcing parts. If your quantity is high enough many of the manufacturers can also customize.

Here are a few of the many Alibaba manufacturers:
[PMMA (acrylic) lenses](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/42MM-muti-angle-3-4-5_60802611184.html)
[Glass Lenses](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Traffic-light-Fresnel-Lens-k9-optical_1600280241725.html)
[Polycarboneate Lenses](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Led-Pc-Lens-50X50MM-4-6_1600173791162.html)

The lenses are made by injection molding; the mold is cut (and subsequently polished) out of steel or aluminum by a CNC milling machine. Any optically clear material can be used to form the lens. The above materials are common choices because they are [UV resistant](https://protoplastics.com/uv-resistant-plastics/) for use outdoors in sunlight.